# call Ajax JQuery on asp:Button OnClientClick and disable page reload if pointer goes to IF condition of Ajax JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a asp:Button (named as "Save") in a Web Page. It has separate code for
**CommandName** and **CommandArgument** defined in a class(.cs) file, to save records.

It also has a **OnClientClick** event code.

**HTML:**

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" CommandName="Update"
OnClientClick="saveButtonClick();" CommandArgument="Save" />
```

Now, When I try to use *OnClick* event of this button, the OnClick code does 
not work. I think its due to CommandName and CommandArgument or OnClientClick
code, already defined on this button but im not sure why its not working.

Since, the *onClick* event is not working, so I thought to write the logic of 
*onClick* through Ajax JQuery and then I want to call this Ajax JQuery 
inside pre-defined function of Javascript called *onClientClick* of this button.

i.e., inside `saveButtonClick();` function of Javascript code

**JavaScript:**

```
<script tyep="text/javscript">
function saveButtonClick() {

   //code

}
</script>
```

**Current Ajax JQuery Code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function saveButtonClick() {

                var chk = {};
                chk.requestID = $("[id*=TempGUID]").text();
                alert(chk.requestID);
                chk.barCode = $("[id*=txtBarcodeNumber]").val();
                alert(chk.barCode);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "IPRForm_EditCheck.aspx/CheckDuplicate",
                    data: '{chk: ' + JSON.stringify(chk) + '}',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {

                        var val = data.d;
                        alert(val);

                        if (val == true) {
                            alert("Barcode Number already exist in system database.");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Barcode Number does not exist");
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (data) {
                        alert(data.responseText);
                    },
                });
                return false;
        }
    </script>
```

**Requirement is** When I click on asp:Button, it triggers the onClientClick event and go to `saveButtonClick()` function of Javscript, inside this function it calls the Ajax JQuery. 
Now, in Ajax JQuery, if pointer goes to IF condition then an alert should come and page *should not reload*, but if it does not goto IF condition, page should reload (as previous default behavior).

I hope I made my requirement clear to you all.
Please note that I am new in asp.net and Ajax JQuery. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```
function saveButtonClick() {

                        var chk = {};
                        chk.requestID = $("[id*=TempGUID]").text();
                        alert(chk.requestID);
                        chk.barCode = $("[id*=txtBarcodeNumber]").val();
                        alert(chk.barCode);

                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: "IPRForm_EditCheck.aspx/CheckDuplicate",
                            data: '{chk: ' + JSON.stringify(chk) + '}',
                            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                            dataType: 'json',
                            async:false,//here I am not allowing event to go further until it checks the barcode existance
                            success: function (data) {

                                var val = data.d;
                                alert(val);

                                if (val == true) {
                                    alert("Barcode Number already exist in system database.");


      return false;

                                }
                                else {

        return true;
                                }

                            },
                            error: function (data) {
                                alert(data.responseText);
                            },
                        });

              }
```

and update as following:

```
<asp:Button ID="yourid" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
OnClientClick="return saveButtonClick()" 
runat="server" />
```

**Explanation:** See, you don't want to trigger the server side code unless bar-code not exists in the database. I have used method [Preventing default behavior of button](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent triggering server-side code. if bar-code doesn't exists than it will trigger the default behavior of the button.

Let me know if it doesn't works.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Going to try your code and will let you know the result.

Comment: I checked your code. No matter pointer goes in IF or ELSE, page gets reload everytime. Due to which if value exist then also it is saved in Database (default behavior). Please reply how to stop the reload of page when it goes in IF condition (i.e., when value exist)

Comment: I had updated my posted question. Please re check again. and I can not use `$("[id*=btnSave]").bind("click", function (e)` inside javascript function because I am calling this ajax jquery on asp button "OnClientClick" event. Please reply how to disable the page reload when pointer is inside Ajax jquery IF condition ?

Comment: @user3196511 It seems you are doing it in a wrong way

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85256/discussion-between-user3196511-and-just-code).

Comment: Thankyou for the help. I tried your updated answer but facing same issue. In ELSE part, page is not loading (to execute default behavior of button) when the entered number do not exist in database. Please reply how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

change your button code like this

```
<asp:Button ID="yourid" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
OnClientClick="return saveButtonClick()" 
runat="server" />
```

JS code:

```
function saveButtonClick()
{
if(condition fails)
return false
else
return true

}
```

EDIT:3
updated JS code,At last I found that async calls cannot return a value, beacuse your code will not stop execution whether you have response from your service or not..please use this solution ,only if you like it..please keep in mind that this is a SYNCHRONOUS call ....

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/json2/0.1/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function saveButtonClick() {


        var result = true;
        var output = $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "Default.aspx/SaveUser",

            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false

        }).responseText;
        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(output);
        if(obj.d) {
            alert("Barcode Number already exist in system database.");
            result = false;
        }
        else {
            alert("entering database");
        }
        alert(result);
        return result;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply. I changed the code as per your suggestion. Now, when I click on button, page do not load when pointer goes to IF condition (as I was expecting) **but** also page do not load when pointer is inside ELSE condition (here I want my page to load, to execute the default behavior of button). Please reply what else I had to change to run my code as expected ?

Comment: if you return true..then it should work..otherwise remove this line "UseSubmitBehavior="false" and try again

Comment: Please check my Javascript code in my posted question. I dont want to load the page when pointer goes into Ajax Jquery IF condition, ELSE have to load the page for normal behavior for button. Please reply what shall I do now ?

Comment: In my posted Ajax JQuery, Last line is returning true or false. Based on that, page is loading. I am checking the condition inside Ajax JQuery not at the end, thatswhy your code is not working for 1 condition. How to change it as per my condition please tel ?

Comment: I tried your updated answer, but I think its not taking the value of result defined under `$.ajax({` code. Whatever we are defining above the `$.ajax` code it is returning that only. Like we declared var result=true so it will return true at the end. If you declare it as false, it will return false at the end. I am really not getting how to solve it. Please help me in anyway.

Comment: Updated answer once again ..please check it now..please also check whether your output is giving 'true' or true

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85189/discussion-between-user3196511-and-aravind).

Comment: Thank you for the help. I tried your updated code again, but what I see is when **output = true**, it is executing ELSE condition & showing ELSE alert not IF one, dont know why. It should go in IF for true since the condition defined like that. But its not working that way. Please let me know why.